# ArcMap "datum transformation is expected, but the parameter is empty" projection error

Tags: coordinate-system, arcmap, convert

I have a feature class in GCS North American 1983 that I need to convert to US National Atlas Equal Area. When I try to use the Project feature in ArcToolbox, after selecting US_National_Atlas_Equal_Area as the output coordinate system, I get this error:

> Warning 001839: A datum transformation is expected, but the parameter
>   is empty.

Comment: This Esri thread about choosing a transformation might be helpful: https://www.esri.com/arcgis-blog/products/product/mapping/about-geographic-transformations-and-how-to-choose-the-right-one/

Comment: The output is an oddball because the GeoCRS is on a sphere, so no transformations.

Answer (score 0):

You will need to supply a transformation.  [This link](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&ved=2ahUKEwi84-WK6JzeAhV1KH0KHRJOAvwQFjAAegQICBAC&url=http%3A%2F%2Fdownloads2.esri.com%2Fsupport%2FTechArticles%2Fgeographic_transformations_1031.pdf&usg=AOvVaw2C5QTqFV9Q0dXEAXZKz3vn) should get you a PDF from ESRI listing the appropriate transformation for your area of interest.  [Here is a link](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/guide-books/map-projections/choosing-an-appropriate-transformation.htm) to some ESRI documentation on transformations.

Comment: you may wish to update the first link to not include the Google Search portion. Direct link:  http://downloads2.esri.com/support/TechArticles/geographic_transformations_1031.pdf

Comment: Thank you. It doesn't look like there are any transformations in these docs for US National Atlas Equal Area though?

Comment: Ah wait, think I just got it converted with geopandas -